# Anchor link in list does span whole of list

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have created a simple vertical nav-bar. On hover, the background colour of the `li` and `a` change. When hovering over the right hand side of the `li` (after the anchor text), everything works fine, but when hovering over the left hand side of the li (before the anchor text) the anchor text becomes invisible (because the anchor text hover style isn't firing).

I have tried to remove `.nav-container ul{padding-left:0px;}` and instead add `display: incline-block` to the `a` themselves, but nothing changes.

Here is a fiddle showing my current approach and demonstrating the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/cf4fe8aL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this css:

```
.nav-container li a:hover {
color: #333;
}
```

with:

```
.nav-container li:hover a{
  color: #333;
}
```

edit 1:

```css
.nav-container {
 border-right: 0.5px solid #333;
 width: 250px;
 float: left;
 background-color: #333;
 height: 100%;
  
}
.nav-container ul{
 width: 100%;
 padding-left:0px;
}
.nav-container ul li {
 list-style-type: none;
 width: 100%;
}
.atag {
  width : 100%;
 display: block;
 text-align: left;
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
 margin-left: 0px;
 padding-left:15px;
}
.atag:hover {
 background-color: #fff;
  color:#333;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>

</head>
<body>
<nav class="nav-container">
      <ul>
       <a class="atag" href="#"><li class="nav-link active">Home</li></a>
       <a class="atag" href="#"><li class="nav-link active">Blog</li></a>
       <a class="atag" href="#"><li class="nav-link active">Store</li></a>
       <a class="atag" href="#"><li class="nav-link active">Contact</li></a>
      </ul>
     </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Awesome works! Is there any way to make the small area to the left of the text clickable too? At the moment when hovering over it, it displays a cursor rather than the hand icon indicating it's a link?

Comment: i have posted an edit , check it out, i think it answers your question :)

Comment: Hey thanks! Everything works exactly how I wanted :)

Comment: glad it helped :)